# simple hover and hover out issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create `hover` and `hover` out via javascript.

I have

```
test.prototype.build = function(){
   other codes...

    link.href         = '#';
    link.innerHTML   += 'test'
    link.onmouseover  = hover
    link.onmouseout   = hoverOut

   other codes...
}





function hover(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.class='testDiv';
        div.innerHTML = 'test';
        $(this).prepend(div);

}


function hoverOut(){
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('testDiv');
        div.style.display='none';

}
```

My task is to create a `hover` and `hover out` function. My problem is I am not sure how to hide the `testDiv` when the user hover out of the link. 
`getElementsByClassName` doesn't seem to work in my case. Are there better way to do this in javascript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I need to use javascript in my case. Thanks though

Comment: Why don't you give an id to the testdiv and then use getElementById? `div.id = 'testDiv'` instead of `div.class='testDiv';`

Comment: getElement **s** ByClassName

it's plural

    `var div = document.getElementsByClassName('testDiv')[0];`

Comment: @Sebas I will have several divs and wish to use simple classname to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('testDiv')` returns an collection, not a single object, but you can probably just use `this` to refer to the current object.  Since you showed some jQuery in your original code, I assume that is OK here.

```
function hoverOut(){
    $(this).find(".testDiv").hide();
}
```

or, in plain javascript, it could be:

```
function hoverOut(){
    var elems = this.getElementsByClassName("testDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Your hover and hoverOut code don't match though because you're creating a new div on hover every time in hover and then only hiding it in hoverOut so they will accumulate.

If you want to remove the div you added in hoverOut(), you can do that like this:

```
function hoverOut(){
    $(this).find(".testDiv").remove();
}
```

or in plain javascript:

```
function hoverOut(){
    var elems = this.getElementsByClassName("testDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i]);
    }
}
```